# Angular set service state using first part of url

Tags: angular, routes

Consider the following urls:

**A:** /things/1 *This navigates to the ThingsComponent*

**B:** /context/3/things/1 *This also navigates to the ThingsComponent but I want id in the ContextService to be set to 3*

Currently in ThingsComponent we are doing something similar to:

```
//the following is for illustration only, it isn't actual code
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private contextService: ContextService,

  ) {
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.contextService.setId(+params['contextId']); 
    });
}
```

The purpose of the ContextService is to change the appearance of the menu structure, which is determined by other components which subscribe to changes in the ContextService.

I don't think that the component should be responsible for this. I feel I've been missing something when studying angular routing, is there not some way to evaluate the first part of the url to set state on my service and then continue processing the second part of the url to provide state to my component?

In terms of an answer I'm looking for either:

- This is not how it is done, a better way of thinking about the problem is ... and this avoids the issue you are facing
- Or the part you are missing is found in the documentation here, and in short this is how it works

Update: As I was writing this question I came across [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) from which I can always return true and since I have access to the router set the state of my service and by applying this to the parent of my  [componentless-routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#componentless-routes) I can set the values for a group of related children. I'm looking over the list of places I can hook into for this functionality, CanLoad works but certainly isn't it's intended purpose.

Comment: Why don't you evaluate the route in the service, and store its state there. You can then pass this service into the components. You may inject `Router` into a service, just like your pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using a resolver.

```
@Injectable()
public class ContextResolver implements Resolve<number> {
    public constructor(private contextService: ContextService) {
    }
    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<number> {
        const id: number = parseInt(route.params['contextId'], 10);
        this.contextService.setId(id);
        return Observable.of(id);
    }
}
```

You then define the route using that resolver.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'context/:contextId/things/:id',
        resolve: {
            ContextID: ContextResolver
        },
        component: ThingsComponent
    }
];
```

You can also add validation rules to the context ID which trigger the failure of the route change if the value is invalid.

It doesn't really matter if the route has children or not. You can always re-use the resolver for any routes that happen to require a `contextId`.

You could also add a `CanDeactive` to set the ID to zero when the user leaves the route.

**UPDATED:**

I was trying to remember why I wouldn't use a `CanActivate` and prefer a `Resolve`.

There can be more than one `CanActivate` assigned to a route. Each will get executed until one yields `false`. That means the service could be set to a `contextId` even if the route does not *change*. The `Resolve` ensures that it's executed after all the `CanActivate` have been called. So you know that the route is actually going to change, and you should then set the state of the service.

`CanDeactive` is the only way to hook into leaving a route.

Comment: Thank you this seems reasonable, I'll test it out today and get back tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for adding the part about CanDeactivate in order to clear the value, I omitted that in all the non-navigation components actually do something like: contextService.setXId(someId); contextService.clearAllButXId(); accounting for that case in this answer was intuitive and very welcome, look forward to testing it.